# EFI System Partition for Dual Boot Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, installation, operating-systems, arch-linux

I just built my first computer and I want to have Windows and Linux installed. My hard drive is on the small side for a dual boot (256 GB SSD), but I plan on upgrading at a later date.

Following the advice of a friend, I installed Windows first on a 200 GB partition. When I installed it, an EFI System Partition was automatically created.

I am currently following the steps of Arch Linux beginner's installation guide. The part I am confused about is:

```
For UEFI, you should format the EFI System Partition with:
# mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdXY 

... 

In case you have a UEFI motherboard, mount the EFI System Partition to /boot.

# mkdir /mnt/boot
# mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot
```

Given that Windows already created the ESP, do I need to format it? And is it even possible to mount it on /boot? Do I need to create a second ESP specifically for Arch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given that Windows already created the ESP, do I need to format it?

No.

> And is it even possible to mount it on /boot?

Yes. In fact, systemd will do that automatically.

> Do I need to create a second ESP specifically for Arch?

No. There must be *exactly one* ESP on a disk.

Comment: Actually, you _can_ have more than one ESP. I have a dual-boot laptop with a separate EFI system partition for each OS and both of them boot just fine.

Comment: @DavidZ: You can, because the EFI boot entries explicitly reference the partition's GUID, but this is not supported in any way.

Comment: Thank you! I thought this was the case but the reassurance is comforting.

Answer (score 0):

256 gigs on an SSD is more than enough. I dunno if you have a laptop or what. What I did is install Arch and run windows in a virtual machine which is probably healthier for the drive. Make sure to mount with Trim enabled and run it on occasion.